# Disposing dynamically created picturebox to release file lock?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to release the file lock on some images so i can move them into an archive folder.

The program loops through the images and adds pictureboxes to a flowlayout panel. After the operation is completed i dispose of the flowlayout panel, and then archive the files.

It is my understanding that disposing the panel will dispose of the picture boxes inside of it, however when i try the move operation i get a IOException Access Denied.

Code:

```
  Dim ImagesInFolder As New List(Of Image)()
    For Each JPEGImages As String In Directory.GetFiles(ExportDir.FullName, "*.jpg")
        ImagesInFolder.Add(Image.FromFile(JPEGImages))
    Next
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To ImagesInFolder.Count - 1
        Dim _image As New PictureBox()
        _image.Location = New Point(x, y)
        x += 50
        _image.Image = ImagesInFolder(i)
        _image.Size = New Size(50, 50)
        _image.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(_image)
    Next
```

Later in the application:

```
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Dispose()
    Directory.Move(CurrentFolder, ArchiveFolder)
```

Comment: I think problem is not with Flowlayout panel but with the Image.FromFile() you are using . you may need to dispose Images in ImagesInFolder list  Try making ImagesInFolder clear and null , if that does not work then try looping and dispose the each Image in it like use foreach and  ((IDisposable)imageObj).Dispose();

Comment: Please let me know if that worked for you i will add that as answer

Comment: If you load images using `Image.FromStram` you don't need to dispose picture boxes.You can take a look at the code for loading images this way in my answer, hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is Because of loading image using `Image.FromFile(file)`.

When you load image using `Image.FromFile(file)` the file will be locked.

To avoid locking file you can load your images using `Image.FromStream`.

**Code:**

```
Dim filePath = "path to your image file"
Dim contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream(contentBytes)
Dim image= Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
YourPictureBox.Image = image
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Sorry for the delay in following back up!